# Implement Bootstrap modal outside click event handler

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to use bootstrap modal in react and have to implement  outside modal click should clear 
the component state and modal close. I am new to front end development and react. I don't want to use react-bootstrap third party library. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean, if you are using bootstrap in a react app you probably should use the react-bootstrap library, it's going to make your job easier.

So if you are not familiar with its use, its pretty simple. First you need to import the library into your project (use npm or yarn). Then you should import the modal component from the library into the react component you are building. Finally you should implement the open and closing functionality as shown in the bootstrap-react documentation. (Note that in the documentation they use react hook useState, so if you are using setState instead is going to be different)

Here is the documentation on how to import the library - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

And here is the documentation on how to implement the component itself on your component - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-overview

Feel free to ask whatever you need

Comment: I told not to use any library like react-bootstrap. I have to use bootstrap for styling but need to handle modal outside click event to clear the state and modal close.